# How do you remove ~, ?, <>, similar

Tags: php

I'm cleaning some input in a form. In some cases I will be removing unwanted characters, in others replacing them with another.

The characters to remove include: & ( ) + <> ? ~
I have tried a couple things:

```
function clean($data) {
  $data = strip_tags(trim($data));
  $replace = array('','~`!@#$%^*/'); // not: & () + <> ? = []
  $data = str_replace($replace, '', $data);

  $data = str_replace ("~","", $data);
  $data = str_replace ("=", '', $data);
  $data = str_replace ('(',"", $data);
  $data = str_replace (')',"", $data);

  $data = str_replace (" ","-", $data);
  $data = ltrim($data, "-"); 
  $data = rtrim($data, "-"); 
  return $data;
}
```

The characters: ~ = ( ) cause the array replacement to fail so I added the additional specific replacements like:

```
$data = str_replace ("~","", $data);
```

This successfully convert an input of:

~~~ hi there== ---()@#~!@&{}$%+=\^*[]/\//=+)(*&^%!@#$%^&*~~

to:

hi-there

which seems to be good. I tried a bunch of variations including escaping () in the array list to try to get it to work on its own, but no dice. Better solution?

Answer (score 1):

For str_replace to work with an array, each character needs to be it's own value.

Example:

```
<?php

$search = array('~','`','!','@','#','$','%','^','*','/','(',')','=','&','{','}','+','-','[',']','\\');
$replace = array('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',  '');

$targetString = '~~~ hi there== ---()@#~!@&{}$%+=\^[]/\//=+)(&^%!@#$%^&*~~';

$newString = str_replace($search, $replace, $targetString);

var_dump($newString);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/LxNAOX

So each value in `$search` has a corresponding value in `$replace`. `$search[0]` goes with `$replace[0]`, `$search[6]` with `$replace[6]`...and on and on. I have the replace values as all blank strings, but you can put any string there you want to replace and they don't all have to be the same if you want.

Although, depending on what you are doing, it might be better to use a regular expression. A regular expression would allow you to create a whitelist of characters instead of a blacklist. Instead of listing every character you don't want to allow and having to constantly add more when someone decides to use upper ascii characters (`ðñòóôõ`...etc) you could use something like this to allow only letters, numbers and spaces:

```
<?php

$targetString = '~~~ hi there== ---()@#~!@&{}$%+=\^[]/\//=+)(&^%!@#$%^&*~~';

$newString = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9 ]+/i', '', $targetString);

var_dump($newString);
```

That essentially says remove any characters that are not `a to z`, `0 to 9` or space.

Comment: The whitelist makes some sense except I think when you data is multi-lingual. Is there a multi-lingual approach?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the multilingual characters. With a whitelist typically you have to list all the characters you want to allow, other languages included. However regular expressions do allow for patterns (such as the `a-z` to represent all letters `a to z`). There might be some sort of pattern you could find that would include several groups of characters.

Comment: There is a multi language approach, and that is also just regex.. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#105924 it is a real nice cheat cheat to the wonderful magic of regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to sanitize just about any special characters, but you don't say why, so what you really need is hard to figure out!

As Jonathan says it is often much better to do the whitelist approach, and for that (And many other things), Regular expressions are great.

Regular expressions have a thing called meta-characters, these can match just about anything you need. Meta characters are used by escaping an otherwise normal character.

`'/\w/'` matches any word-character regardless of language, and capital `'/\W/'` does the opposite.

I have found this particular comment in the PHP manual useful for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#105924